# ERROR 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 - still happening

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

Well although I was looking for the same questions in SO to find a solution there is nothing to solve my problem.

The problem is:

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`users` (`username`, `password`, `info_id`) 
VALUES ('myname', '123456', 2)`
```

and I can't understand where is the problem.

The table looks like that: users(id, username, password, info_id) where the id is auto incremented.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't believe that.I created similar structure of table and it inserted ok.Are you sure about that? can you post SHOW CREATE TABLE users?

Comment: can you reformulate the question and put it in the body?

Comment: @Albin Yes finally that was the problem, I had a misspelled column in a trigger of this table. But to me it looks very strange that mysql doesn't show anything about the trigger where the problem was, it is confusing. Thanks all of you for your reply.

Comment: Add it as an answer an accept it so it can be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers can cause this kind of behaviour if the insert in the trigger is malfunctioning.